# EFCore.BulkExtensions How to update records on condition?

Tags: entity-framework, entity-framework-core, bulkinsert, bulkupdate, efcore.bulkextensions

I am using **EFCore.BulkExtensions** for insert and update records in a table. But I have a problem with update records on condition.

For example, I have 15 records (10 to insert, 5 to update). I need to insert 10, but update only 2, because 3 records have old value in UpdatedAt property (database contains more recent data).

If I use **EFCore.BulkExtensions** like this:

```
_dbContext.BulkInsertOrUpdateAsync(entitiesList, _bulkConfig);
```

10 records will be inserted and 5 records will be updated. So the data in the database will be updated by older ones.

To solve my problem I want something like this:

```
_dbContext.BulkInsertOrUpdateAsync(entitiesList, _bulkConfig,
    (oldRecord, newRecord) => newRecord.UpdatedAt > oldRecord.UpdatedAt);
```

Can you suggest some efficient way to solve this problem with **EFCore.BulkExtensions**?

Comment: Simple question. Are you stick with this third party library, or you are open to use something other?

Comment: @SvyatoslavDanyliv it's preferably to use EFCore.BulkExtensions, but not necessarily. I am open to look at some other solutions.

Answer (score 0):

This is not direct answer for `EFCore.BulkExtensions`, but alternative how to do that with [linq2db.EntityFrameworkCore](https://github.com/linq2db/linq2db.EntityFrameworkCore). Note that I'm one of the creators.

```cs
await context.SomeTable
    .ToLinqToDBTable()
    .Merge()
    .Using(entitiesList)
    .On((t, s) => t.Id == s.Id)
    .InsertWhenNotMatched()
    .UpdateWhenMatchedAnd((t, s) => s.UpdatedAt > t.UpdatedAt)
    .MergeAsync();
```

Select appropriate package 2.x for EF Core 2.x, 3.x for EF Core 3.1.x, etc.

Comment: UpdateWhenMatchedAnd() method works on server side or client side? I mean, do we need to load all the entities to update on the client side to check the condition `s.UpdatedAt > t.UpdatedAt` before build an update SQL query?

Comment: Everything on the server side. If there are thousand records, better to put them into temporary table first. `linq2db` provides such functionality.

Comment: All the SQL actions will be in a transaction scope? Is it possible to rollback all the changes?

Comment: Documentation [MERGE](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/statements/merge-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2016)

Comment: Trying to use it. What should I pass in `InsertWhenNotMatchedAnd()` method? Your code is not compiling right now.

Comment: 'IMergeableSource<ActiveBonus, TEntity>' does not contain a definition for 'InsertWhenNotMatched'

Comment: Actually copied from working code. Probably `using linq2db;` needed or package not installed correctly.

Comment: `using LinqToDB;
using LinqToDB.EntityFrameworkCore;`

    `<PackageReference Include="linq2db" Version="4.0.1" />
    <PackageReference Include="linq2db.EntityFrameworkCore" Version="6.8.0" />
    <PackageReference Include="linq2db.SqlServer" Version="4.0.1" />`

Comment: Edit my answer and paste how do you use library. Post exact code.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/245178/discussion-between-phil-and-svyatoslav-danyliv).